# Netbeans Official Shortcut List

Tags: netbeans, shortcut

How come no one has posted this list yet? Everyone replies to a netbeans shortcuts question with a single shortcut or a few shortcuts, but I find this list to be useful.

**NetBeans Official Shortcut List:**

**[Netbeans Shortcuts](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf)**

Comment: Good post. You should edit it into a question format, then answer your own question. That is allowed :)

Comment: It's not a good post unless it's Q&A. And, on the other hand, this PDF is the first search result when googling `netbeans shortcuts` anyway.

Comment: @peeskillet thank you, I will try to make that change now

Comment: When I need it I simply use `Help -> Keyboard Shortcuts Card` from inside NetBeans.